# Pivot rod in bathroom sink too tight

Tags: plumbing

Ok, changed out the pivot rod, old one was broken. Put new one in, But. By the time I have the retaining nut tight enough to stop leaks. The pivot rod won't move? Loosen it to help movement, but starts leaking again. I bought the full kit, the bigger ball doesn't fit into hole, has to be the little one.. what am I doing wrong??

Comment: Remove  it and check the drain pipe where the ball sits and make sure the surface is smooth. If it's course and corroded, you might have to change the pipe.

Comment: Are there seals on both sides of the ball?  Maybe one is missing?

Answer (score 3):

If it’s corroded, you need to replace the tailpiece.  If it was me, I’d find a plain tailpiece and a popup drain.  Those rods are often problematic.

Comment: Popup drains are great.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Comment: I don't like popups but if the OP has the "full kit"... imo that means it came with *a new tailpiece*, +1. But if they already did that, they need to work it back and forth about a hundred times, tightening it a bit at a time until that magic spot where it still sucks but it works and doesn't leak.

Answer (score 1):

You need the same size ball as the original, different manufacturers use different sizes, and a larger ball will not seal properly.